# Singularities of $\sin(z)/(1-\cos(\sqrt{z}\,))$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, singularity-theory

$\displaystyle f(z) = \frac{\sin(z)}{1-\cos(\sqrt{z}\,)}$.

The assignment is to find all the singularities of $f$, determine the type of them and the residue.

It is clear that the singularities are $z_k = (2k\pi)^2$ with $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. I'm not allowed to use l'Hôpital so I could try to develop a Laurent series or using the Taylor series of $\cos(\sqrt{z}\,) = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n }{(2n)!}z^n$ and $\sin(z) = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n }{(2n+1)!}z^{2n+1}$ but I can't of a way to determine the solution.

Comment: The singularities are where $\sqrt{z}=\frac\pi 2$, i.e., where $z=[\pi(\frac{2k+1}{2})]^2$

Comment: @MPW Why should they? They are where $\cos(\sqrt{z}\,)=1$, that is, for $\sqrt{z}=2k\pi$.

Comment: $\cos 2\pi k = 1$. You are thinking of $\sin$ instead, perhaps?

Comment: @MPW Yes, so $1-\cos2k\pi=0$; am I missing something?

Comment: @egreg: You are right, of course. I am mistaken. DOH!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the fact that
$$
\lim_{z\to0}\frac{1-\cos(\sqrt{z}\,)}{z}=\frac{1}{2}
$$
which follows from the Taylor series, so you have
$$
\lim_{z\to0}\frac{\sin z}{1-\cos\sqrt{z}}=
\lim_{z\to0}\frac{\sin z}{z}\frac{z}{1-\cos\sqrt{z}}=2
$$
and $0$ is a removable singularity.

Let's look at $4k^2\pi^2$, where $k\ne0$. Since $\sin(4k^2\pi^2)\ne0$, because $\pi$ is irrational, we know we have a singularity. However,
$$
\lim_{z\to4k^2\pi^2}\frac{(z-4k^2\pi^2)^2}{1-\cos\sqrt{z}}=
\lim_{w\to2k\pi}\frac{(w^2-4k^2\pi^2)^2}{1-\cos w}=
\lim_{u\to0}\frac{u^2(u+4k\pi)^2}{1-\cos u}=32k^2\pi^2
$$
(by taking a suitable branch for the square root and doing $w-2k\pi=u$).

Thus $4k^2\pi^2$ is a pole of order $2$.

Comment: The zeroes of $\sin z$ are integral multiples of $\pi$. $\sin 0 = 0, \cos 0 = 1$.

Comment: @MPW And what does this imply? I don't understand; here and in the comments to the question you seem to believe that the singularities are where $\cos\sqrt{z}=0$, which makes no sense.

Comment: As I commented above, you are correct. I was misreading the problem. Apologies.

Comment: @egreg I understood your argumentation for prooving that $0$ is a removable singularity and thus $res_0 f = 0$. It is also possible to purely use the Taylor series of both $\cos$ and $\sin$ to prove that $\lim_{z \rightarrow 0} f(z) = \frac{1}{1/2} = 2$ after you factorize a z in numerator and denominator. To be honest, the calculation of the limit at $4k^2\pi^2$ is something I've never seen with substitutions and such but it's easy to comprehend :) . What about the residue at $4k^2\pi^2$ though?

Comment: @PeterMcCoy I'll try a hint (after doing the computations myself).

Comment: @PeterMcCoy If $f$ has a pole at $a$ of order $2$, then $f(z)=\frac{A}{(z-a)^2}+\frac{B}{z-a}+g(z)$ with $g$ holomorphic at $a$. Note that we know the value of $A$ by the previous argument. Then $B=\lim_{z\to a}(z-a)\left(f(z)-\frac{A}{(z-a)^2}\right)$. Boring, but doable with similar substitution tricks and final Taylor development.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for your great solution, however I think $\lim_{u\to 0} \frac{u^2(u+4k\pi)}{1-\cos(u)}=512k^4\pi^4$.

Comment: @runner.87 $\lim_{u\to0}\frac{1-\cos u}{u^2}=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @egereg  Yes, you are indeed correct.  I apologize for the mix-up.